# What would happen if a user is killed in the Grid?

Tags: tron-legacy, tron

What happens if a user(human), dies while in the computer?

Comment: Game over, man... Game over!

Comment: Would the appropriate term for a User be "DeRezzed", or does that only apply to Programs?

Comment: It only applies to Programs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, to an extent we need to distinguish which source we're looking at (and later, as an extra, the method of death):

1. (the original) Tron.
   Users are the gods to the people of the grid. There's no real indication that Users even can be killed. Flynn manages to perform a few tasks that are seemingly impossible for others to do. Flynn can be hurt, but killed? Maybe not. When others fall far enough from the grid, they end up derezzing. Flynn may well have fallen to the bottom, picked himself up and limped off. Again, remember that he was meant to be a god compared to the Grid world, and as such may well have been effectively immortal.
2. Tron 2.0 (Killer App):
   This is dealt with to an extent in the game, though my memory is a touch fuzzy on the matter. Two opposite examples spring to mind.

a) the compiled Tron Legacy Code shows that apparently that version of Tron (which was originally designed as a system security software) was designed to protect the system, but due to a glitch in the code, interpreted those orders as killing Users, presumably permanently.

b) the Datawraiths are company backed hackers. Instead of being directly digitized into the world, they sort-of take control of designed on-Grid puppets. Thus when the puppet's bodies are destroyed, the Hacker wakes up again in the main office.

Now, at one point Thorne is digitized, but the digitization algorithm is flawed, causing Thorne to become a virus in the system. Thorne certainly dies on the grid. However, he is arguably a flawed copy of a User on the system, and as such retains many of the powers of Users but with limitations not present with a perfectly digitized User- like being able to die.

Importantly, whether or not a User could be infected by such a virus is unanswered. However, it could set up a possibility where the Programs have a form of biological warfare capable of rendering a User mortal and thus killable.

3. Tron Legacy proof-of-concept trailer (a.k.a. TR2N trailer):
   I'm distinguishing this somewhat because the original trailer came out several years before the movie, and was really there just to see if there would be any interest in making such a creature as a sequel. Which, now that I think about it, is kind of funny considering it's Hollywood and they mostly make sequels these days. But I digress.
   We see what is arguably a User (and possibly a hacker) taken out by Clu. This is particularly noteworthy because of the lines:

User: You won, okay? It's just a game!

Clu: Not anymore.

Which is followed by what appears to be some sort of death blow, presumably to protect the Grid world from intrusion from the Users. One presumes that at this point, the idea was that knowledge of the Grid was a touch more widely known, and that the programs were rebelling against their creators because they were sick and tired of them dragging their trash into their nice clean Grid.

4. Tron: Legacy.

Tricky. There were some fundamental changes between the two movies. During the ARG before the movie, I calculated that Kevin Flynn had survived a conservative ~63 million subjective years in the Grid. Our conversations were being followed, and apparently nobody at Disney had actually bothered to do the math, so they scrambled to say that it had been about a thousand subjective years. So we know that there are differences in the original Grid and Flynn's Grid, and we can see that Flynn is clearly aging in the Grid, though as a slower rate. The end blast doesn't actually show Flynn dying, being derezzed, or anything. And, not to put too fine a point on it, the entire byline of the advertising campaign as "Flynn Lives" which seems to indicate that he never died originally and possibly didn't die at the end either. What exactly happened isn't really indicated, tho.

However, we know that Users can be hurt, as shown by the blood drops from Sam during the Sam/Rinzler fight. And to quote that old classic: if it can bleed, we can kill it. We know from the original Tron that Users can absolutely grow tired, though they can recharge either through system resources or simply by sleeping (note that in the original, we never see any of the programs sleep- any why should they? They're programs.) Sam can bleed. Flynn can age. So there does seem to be a hint that Users can now in actuality die in the Grid.

So, we have to examine the fundamental underpinning of why Users were so unique on the Grid. The digitization process allowed a material to be transformed into pure code. Still a program, but highly complex. We ignore the question of how a 1980's era mainframe would have the power to run a single program as complicated as a human being. So what was so special about the ISOs? How were they necessarily distinguished from Users?

This was examined in the prequel comic book miniseries tied in to the movie, Tron:Betrayal. Flynn created his Grid where Programs could be free to not feel compelled to forcibly follow their programming. But he began to see that what he imagined could never be- the programs were too simple, too limited. To use a programming analogy, a Hello World Program wouldn't be interested in expanding its capabilities, as it is only designed for one single purpose. To use a religious allegory, Flynn created the Garden, and found his creations to be flawed.

But around the Grid was an ocean of chaos. The raw firmament of unspecified information. Noise, randomness, excess energy. And out of it, spontaneously, evolved the ISOs. The ISOs, while being programs, had naturally evolved, and as such were naturally significantly more complex than the old Programs. The ISOs were meant to be the new Users of the Grid world. Like with us having DNA which is programming but which we can often overcome, the ISOs were unrestricted. While not explicitly stated in either the comic book or the movie, there is something of an implication that the ISOs are possibly superior to Man.

And the ISOs were all killed.

Which partially begs the question- what makes Flynn unique? Why could he do things that the ISOs couldn't do? Well, I think it may well have less to do with his code at that point, and more to do with his fundamental understanding of how the Grid actually functions. How and why does energy flow, what is code, and how can it be manipulated, etc. etc. etc. That is, if you don't want to look at it from the religious angle, which more or less would argue that Users have a unique spirit or soul which is transferred to the digital realm and makes them mightier. And considering how the stories have always been religious allegories, this may well be true.

So, Tron:Legacy does seem to indicate that at the very least Users can be violently killed, even if not quite explicitly stated. However, what about Flynn? Can Flynn, if we wait long enough, die of old age? What, exactly, *is* aging for a User on the Grid?

Well, the original Tron showed old programs as being programs which had been around for a great deal of time, but this never detracted from their capacity to fulfill their function (At least until that function had changed). Even the MCP is briefly shown to be an old man, and in the novelization is described as being incredibly old, and still using old-fashioned keyboards as his interface with the world (whereas you never otherwise see keyboards in the world) and in the movie you can actually hear the clacking of a mechanical keyboard as the MCP is dying.

So, can a program die of old age? We've yet to see evidence. And in the real world, software gets outdated, forgotten, abandoned- but it never stops being a program. It never erases itself after aging. The media it is stored on might, but the program itself doesn't. So I think that with that argument, a program would continue to grow older without actually dying. If this is the case, I would argue that at the very least the same can be said of Flynn.

5. Tron, the novelization

As memory serves, Flynn wonders this himself briefly, and decides that he really, really doesn't want to know the answer.

6. Tron Legacy ARG: this never came up.

Well, this answer turned out to be a touch longer than I anticipated.

Comment: Good answer. This seems to cover all the bases.

Answer (score 1):

In *Tron Legacy*, Kevin Flynn merged with Clu, killing them both.  There was a large explosion in the Grid, but no manifestation of the calamity in the outside world. Barring further exposition in a future film, Flynn stays dead.

Comment: There's also no exposition about what happened to his constituent components, the ones being stored below the laser.

Comment: The original Tron has one of laser scientists saying "digitized".  Unlike ST:TNG, there is no "pattern buffer" or atoms being held "in storage". This is a complete rendering into digital information, not your typical sci-fi teleporation-by-breakdown.

Comment: There is no indication whatsoever that Flynn and Clu were killed in the merge.